# Generalization of Lambert W function?

Tags: real-analysis, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

Can the function $f(x)$ defined by
$$ x = f(x)^2 e^{f(x)}$$
for real $x>0$ be expressed in relation to the Lambert W Function?

Comment: Just square root both sides...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Simply Beautiful Art mention in the comments, take square roots of both sides in the equation

$$x=f(x)^2 e^{f(x)} $$

and get

$$\sqrt{x}=f(x) e^{\frac{f(x)}{2}} .$$

Now divide by two both sides

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}=\frac{f(x)}{2} e^{\frac{f(x)}{2}} $$

Using definition of Lambert W function, we write

$$\frac{f(x)}{2} = W(\pm \sqrt{x}/2) $$

and get

$$f(x) = 2 W(\pm \sqrt{x}/2).$$

As Robert showed in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x) = 2 W(\pm \sqrt{x}/2)$$

Comment: Lovely. Just so I remember why: $$ e^{f(x)} = (e^{W(\sqrt{x}/2)})^2 = \frac{x}{2W(\sqrt{x}/2)} = \frac{x}{f(x)^2} $$

Comment: Errata: second last should be $$\frac{x}{4W(\sqrt{x}/2)}$$ of course.

Answer (score 2):

As written by Robert your function can be written as:

$f(x)=2W({\sqrt{x}\over 2})$

And in general every function of the form:

$x=f^n(x)e^{f(x)}$

Can be written as:

$f(x)=nW({x^{\frac 1n}\over n})$

Comment: Hello, Renato. Could you provide an article that is giving a proof of the equality which you introduce in your answer?